# Embedding Quartz into ASP.NET application with always run

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net, iis-10

I had an on-going enterprise development which involved Quartz to do daily/weekly jobs such as

- Clean up temporary folder
- Send Emails
- Update databases
- Publish items

and I'm embedding Quartz into an ASP.NET application with always run, no idle timeout, & recycles app pool every day at 4am, & it works perfectly.

I've been searching on Stackoverflow & many people suggested to make it a Windows service, however those answers were a few years old - before IIS 8 became available.

I wonder if my implementations has some cons & will cause side effects that yet to be known? Only 1 ASP.NET application to be run in this machine.

Comment: If you do know well enough on enterprise development, you should know how important it is to keep things simple, so that when issues arise you immediately know what might be wrong and respond swiftly. Putting scheduled tasks and ASP.NET in the same process can only give you pains as even the tiniest issue can be hard to track down. Why should some great answers be neglected simply because they are "old"?

Comment: May I know why putting them together will have issues of tracking down? I've been using logger to monitor all my process & they're worked great in finding issues. I find harder to trace after putting it into Windows Service. It's harder to debug & deploy in staging server. And those years old answer were pointing to prior IIS 7.5 & some were suggesting both methods has no different as long as we kept IIS running all the time.

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870562/pros-and-cons-of-running-quartz-net-embedded-or-as-a-windows-service